# What could be causing forced SSL on WordPress Login page? (ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT)

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I'm working on a site that is share hosted at ipower(dot)com. I went to login via Wordpress. But after I entered my login credentials, I got forwarded to an https login page with the error: ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

The url I start with is http://chpconsultants.com/wp-admin or /wp-login.php. Every time I enter my login credentials and then press the login button, I get routed to https version of those links.

After I've tried to login, if I go to the front end of the site, I can see the admin  toolbar across the top of the page, but if I click on anything in the toolbar, I again get routed to an https page with the ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error.

This is a wordpress site, v. 4.8.2. PHP version 5.6.30. It's using a basic version of Sitelock, so a firewall/CDN. I don't have, and can't get, SSH access.

Here's what I've done to try and fix it so far:

1) Going into the mysql db into wp_options and checking that the urls    in both the siteurl and home are using http and not https
2) Deactivating all my plugins to ensure no conflict 
3) Cleaning out my .htaccess file and re-setting it with the default wordpress .htaccess
4) Adding this to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

5) Adding this to my wpconfig file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://chpconsultants.com');    
define('WP_SITEURL','http://chpconsultants.com');
```

6) adding this to my wpconfig file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

7) adding this to functions.php:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://chpconsultants.com'); 
update_option( 'home', 'http://chpconsultants.com' );
```

8) Clearing the wordpress cache numerous times throughout the above steps

9) Purging the SiteLock cache numerous times throughout this process

10) Creating a new wp user through the database and trying to login with    that. I got the same https results

11) Contacting Sitelock to ask if there was anything in the firewall that might be forcing SSL. I spoke with a great tech support person there, who also happened to be highly experienced with wordpress. He actually took a look at the site himself and replicated the issue. He also looked at several things including all of the above steps I did and verified he saw    nothing in the site that could be causing this problem.

If you've read this far, thanks for looking! Please forgive any formatting clumsiness. I'm still a newb on posting here.

Given all of the above, does anyone have any good idea of what else I might try? Or what might be causing this?

Thanks,

Mieren

Comment: Have you tried going around Sitelock (e.g. putting your hostname in your local hosts file) to see whether the problem is on their end?

Comment: I haven't specifically put my hostname in local hosts file. I'm not sure what that means or how I would do it.
However, I turned off their firewall/cdn at one point and the issue remained.

Comment: It'd allow you to bypass their tech. Search for hosts file + your OS, grab your real servers' IP and put it in there as `ip chpconsultants.com`. Restart your browser and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Ok. Tried putting the server ip in my hosts file. It caused a slightly different behaviour in the browser, meaning this time it gave me the "you're about to go to a non-secure site" message. But then again took me to the https url.

Comment: FYI, I have tried logging in from different browser and from different computers, including my 4G network. And have asked someone else to try from another location. They also got the forced SSL login page.

Comment: When you bypassed Sitelock and made chrome proceed to the unsafe site, did it work or did you get the same error? It's always hard to debug these things with a black box in the middle where you don't exactly know what it does, how it caches etc pp. Do you have any certificate set up at your host?

Comment: When I bypassed sitelock and told Chrome to proceed, it did not work. It again forwarded me to the https url and gave me the ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error.

I'm digging into the ipower control panel and have just discovered an SSL page that says:

At IPOWER, any file that you can access via your domain can be accessed through a Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connection as well.

To access any of your files through a SSL connection, use the following URL:
https://mydomain.ipower.com/<anyfile>
... where <anyfile> is the name of any file in your web directory.

Comment: But I haven't otherwise assigned an SSL cert to this domain. I'll dig further on that point from their SSL page.

Comment: I discovered that did not fully disable the plugins. Originally I disabled my plugins by renaming the plugins folder. However, some were still active unbeknownst to me. I had to go into the wp_options table and disable them as per https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_disable_all_wordpress_plugins_directly_from_database/  which solved the forced SSL. I am now getting a different error re reauth=1 loop, but I'm considering this issue solved. Thanks @janh2 for chiming in.

Comment: @janh or Mieren you should put the solution as an answer to help future readers of this qustion.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Bluehost Plus and had this error on one of my sub domains which had worked before. I had attempted to enable their free Beta CDN in addition to the existing SSL which triggered this issue on one of the sub domains but not another that I did the same to.

Support told me SSL and their CDN were not compatible together - the CDN install on the performance tab of the bluehost wordpress control panel is still hanging 3 days later with the spinning wheel saying "We're setting up your CDN. For now, feel free to start exploring WordPress or jump into building your website." Occasionally an 'unhandled exception' banner error shows up.

The first support agent said he would try to disable the cdn which could take 14 hrs to propogate which made no difference.

The 2nd support agent seemed confident of a fix by changing the A records and said it may take 4 hrs to propogate. This fixed it for me and I can now access all subdomains on SSL. The Performance tab is still hanging and creating errors though.

Comment: how long did you wait for A records changes to propagate?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue after upgrading from Basic Hosting to Plus Hosting on Bluehost and importing a new domain. I used the Free SSL from the Wordpress Tools, and was getting the above error on my HTTPS version (although HTTP was fine).

I had to open three tickets within 24 hours with their support, finally on the third time it was resolved.

The first two support people said it was an issue with SiteLock not working with SSL, so Sitelock would need to be disabled. After waiting the 4-8 hours they said it would take, there was no change.

The second go around was the same, except after waiting a little, my site instead gave the "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error. After clicking the "Proceed Anyway" button, my site actually redirected to a random, completely different site I didn't own. Less than ideal...

The third support tech said the SSL cert needed to be uninstalled and reapplied, again with a 4-8 hour window. However, the site began working minutes after he said the changes were pending - so not really sure what's going on over at Bluehost. I get the feeling many of the Level 1 Support Techs don't have much technical expertise.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and contacted help. They changed the IP address and it started working right away. This was my case ID 00D36qEW6._50036dOPVh

Hope this helps someone